# angular 6 pwa does not work at all with service workers

Tags: service-worker, angular6, angular-service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I did a simple

```
ng g myapp --service-worker
```

this creates a blank app. I am expecting it to add service worker and configure by default. however it does not happen. running chrome based web server and running lightroom audit shows the error

> "Does not register a service worker"

i am not sure where is the issue.

plz advise

screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ux16n4i4u4h3gt/Screen%20Shot%202018-05-29%20at%209.51.01%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue.

Solution: add the PWA support later on:

```
   ng add @angular/pwa --project <your project name>
```

Answer (score 0):

enter the project dir `cd <your-project>` and then 
`ng add @angular/pwa`

**Ref:** 
which will add the pwa to your project with all the service worker related stuff which we don’t need to do it manually.
see `git clone https://github.com/ng-model/pwa.git`